# Is there a way to disconnect the post_delete signal in simple history?

Tags: django, django-simple-history

I need to bulk_create the historical records for each object deleted in a queryset.  I've coded it correct I think as follows.

```
def bulk_delete_with_history(objects, model, batch_size=None, default_user=None, default_change_reason="", default_date=None):
    """
    The package `simple_history` logs the deletion one object at a time.  
    This does it in bulk.
    """
    model_manager = model._default_manager
    model_manager.filter(pk__in=[obj.pk for obj in objects]).delete()

    history_manager = get_history_manager_for_model(model)

    history_type = "-"
    historical_instances = []
    for instance in objects:
        history_user = getattr(
            instance,
            "_history_user",
            default_user or history_manager.model.get_default_history_user(
                instance),
        )
        row = history_manager.model(
            history_date=getattr(
                instance, "_history_date", default_date or timezone.now()
            ),
            history_user=history_user,
            history_change_reason=get_change_reason_from_object(
                instance) or default_change_reason,
            history_type=history_type,
            **{
                field.attname: getattr(instance, field.attname)
                for field in instance._meta.fields
                if field.name not in history_manager.model._history_excluded_fields
            }
        )
        if hasattr(history_manager.model, "history_relation"):
            row.history_relation_id = instance.pk
        historical_instances.append(row)

    return history_manager.bulk_create(
        historical_instances, batch_size=batch_size
    )
```

The problem though is I need to disconnect the post_delete signal so that a historical record isn't created by simple history before i do it all at once.

I've tried this but it doesn't work.

```
models.signals.post_delete.disconnect(HistoricalRecords.post_delete, sender=Customer)
```

Where `Customer` is just a class I'm using to test this utility function.

Can anybody advise?  Thanks in advance.

Asked the question on their github page also - https://github.com/jazzband/django-simple-history/issues/717

Answer (score 0):

I made a classic mistake with disconnecting signals.  One must of course disconnect with the object that was connected.  This is discussed here in more detail - [django signal disconnect not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35386423/django-signal-disconnect-not-working)

This now works because I am disconnecting with reference to the correct object.

```
        receiver_object = models.signals.post_delete._live_receivers(Customer)[0]
        models.signals.post_delete.disconnect(receiver_object, sender=Customer)
```

Still, I think it would be nice if django-simple-history provided a bulk_delete utility function like they provide one for bulk_create and bulk_update.